# Page header and content is overlaping while printing in react. using react to print

Tags: reactjs, media-queries, printing-web-page, react-to-print

I want to print a page, that overlaps page header with page content, also Page number not working. i am using react-to-print. And below css for styling

I want to print a page with page number without any overlapping and proper page breaking.

Here this code prints the data from array of objects and prints in table format and print button prints the table in multiple pages with header and footer

```js
import React, { useContext, useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import ReactToPrint, { useReactToPrint } from 'react-to-print';
import Header from './Header'
import Footer from './Footer'
import Image from '../images/logo192.png'


export default function Home() {

    const print_details = [
        {
            _id: 1,
            description: "Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta.",
            date: "2023/02/02",
            price: 20000,
            gst: "18%",

        },
        {
            _id: 2,
            description: "Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta.",
            date: "2023/02/02",
            price: 20000,
            gst: "18%",

        },
        {
            _id: 3,
            description: " Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta.",
            date: "2023/02/02",
            price: 20000,
            gst: "18%",

        },
        {
            _id: 4,
            description: " Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta",
            date: "2023/02/02",
            price: 20000,
            gst: "18%",

        },
        {
            _id: 5,
            description: "Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta.",
            date: "2023/02/02",
            price: 20000,
            gst: "18%",

        },
        {
            _id: 6,
            description: " Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta.",
            date: "2023/02/02",
            price: 20000,
            gst: "18%",

        },
        {
            _id: 7,
            description: "Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta.",
            date: "2023/02/02",
            price: 20000,
            gst: "18%",

        },
        {
            _id: 8,
            description: "Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta.",
            date: "2023/02/02",
            price: 20000,
            gst: "18%",

        },
        {
            _id: 9,
            description: "Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta.",
            date: "2023/02/02",
            price: 20000,
            gst: "18%",

        },
        {
            _id: 10,
            description: "Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta.",
            date: "2023/02/02",
            price: 20000,
            gst: "18%",

        },
        {
            _id: 11,
            description: "Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta.dicta.",
            date: "2023/02/02",
            price: 20000,
            gst: "18%",

        },
        {
            _id: 12,
            description: "Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta.",
            date: "2023/02/02",
            price: 20000,
            gst: "18%",

        },
        {
            _id: 13,
            description: " Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta. ",
            date: "2023/02/02",
            price: 20000,
            gst: "18%",

        },
        {
            _id: 14,
            description: "Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta.",
            date: "2023/02/02",
            price: 20000,
            gst: "18%",

        },
        {
            _id: 15,
            description: " Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta.",
            date: "2023/02/02",
            price: 20000,
            gst: "18%",

        },
        {
            _id: 16,
            description: "Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta.",
            date: "2023/02/02",
            price: 20000,
            gst: "18%",

        },
        {
            _id: 17,
            description: "Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta.",
            date: "2023/02/02",
            price: 20000,
            gst: "18%",

        },
        {
            _id: 18,
            description: "Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta.",
            date: "2023/02/02",
            price: 20000,
            gst: "18%",

        },
        {
            _id: 19,
            description: "Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta.",
            date: "2023/02/02",
            price: 20000,
            gst: "18%",

        },
        {
            _id: 20,
            description: "Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis hic modi necessitatibus, tempore, eligendi ea nihil facere quam eum placeat nisi suscipit maxime. Animi incidunt, inventore deleniti rerum exercitationem dicta.",
            date: "2023/02/02",
            price: 20000,
            gst: "18%",

        },
    ];


    const ref = useRef(null);
    const componentHeaderRef = useRef();

   
    const printvariable = useReactToPrint({
        content: () => ref.current,
        documentTitle: "this is the document Title",
        
    });

    

    const Printvalues = () => {
        // var totalPages = Math.ceil(ref.current.scrollHeight);
        // console.log(totalPages)
        setTimeout(() => {
            printvariable();
        }, 500);
    }

    let array = [];
    


    return (

        <>
            <center>
                
                <Button style={{ marginTop: "50px" }} variant="primary" onClick={Printvalues}>Print</Button>



                <div className="start" ref={ref}>

                    <div className="Header"><Header /></div>


                    <Table className="content" border={1} striped style={{ width: "80%", marginTop: "60px" }}>


                        <thead className="thead" style={{ marginTop: "50px" }}>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {print_details.map((item, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <tr className="tr_content" key={index}>
                                        <td>{item._id}</td>
                                        <td>{item.description}</td>
                                        <td>{item.date}</td>
                                        <td>{item.price}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                )
                            })}


                        </tbody>

                    </Table>
                    <div className='Footer' ><Footer /></div>

                    <div className='pagenumber' id='pagenumber'>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </center>
        </>
    )
}
```

```css
body {
    counter-reset: page;
}

@page {
    counter-increment: page;
    counter-reset: page 1;
}

@media print {
    .Footer {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .Header {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 9999;
        margin-bottom: 100px;
        padding-top: 130;
    }

    table {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }

    thead {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: red;
        margin-top: 30px;
    }

    tr {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/0.14.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello. I'm the maintainer of `react-to-print`. We [intentionally remove](https://github.com/gregnb/react-to-print/blob/de4c04b5472ccf00e3fdcd8f333fb4faf066e0b2/src/index.tsx#L31-L43) the page numbers and a few other things since the goal is normally to print a specific component, not whole pages. You can restore them by setting the `pageStyle` prop to `""` or to some other set of styles you prefer

Comment: @MatthewHerbst  I am not using default page number, customized page number using js will give some extra pages when page breaks

Comment: You'll have to show some code and examples of the issue please

Comment: @MatthewHerbst i added coed what i am trying, pls help me to fix this